# Keep one occurrence of all numbers in a linked list

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I want to find an algorithm to keep only one occurrence of each number in a linked list using recursion
,I know recursion is not at all a good choice to solve this problem ,but I want to try it.

for more calirification:

```
input : 1->2->1->3->3->2->1->4

output : 1->2->3->4
```

Here is the program that i've made to keep only one occurrence of a given number using recursion, but i couldn't develop it in order to solve the whole problem. can I get some help? thanks in advance.

```
list* wipe(list* head,int val)
{
    if(head==NULL)  return head;
    static int occ=1;
    if(head->data == val)
    {
        if(occ-- < 1)
        {
            list* temp=head;
            head=head->next;
            free(temp);
            return wipe(head,val);
        }
    }
    head->next=wipe(head->next,val);
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Traverse and do kind of modified insertion sort to insert the numbers into a new linked list. Modified in terms that t won't insert duplicate numbers.

Comment: @LEARNER What is the whole problem?

Comment: *occ* is set to 1 only the very time you execute the function, so from the second time `(head->data == val)` is true **whatever *val*** the test `(occ-- < 1)` will be true => cannot work

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the whole problem is to keep only one occurrence of all numbers, i have only found the solution to keep one occurrence of one give number, i want to do the same for all the numbers that i have in my linked list

Comment: the solution is simple, see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*occ* is set to 1 only the very time you execute the function, so from the second time `(head->data == val)` is true whatever *val* the test `(occ-- < 1)` will be true, this is not the right way.

You can do something like that where the list is modified to only contain unique numbers :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct List {
  struct List * next;
  int data;
} List;

/* remove from l all the cells having data equals to v */
List * wipe(int v, List * l)
{
  if (l == NULL)
    return l;
  else if (l->data != v) {
    l->next = wipe(v, l->next);
    return l;
  }
  else {
    List * n = l->next;
    
    free(l);
    return wipe(v, n);
  }
}

/* modify the argument to not have duplicated numbers */
void simplify(List * l)
{
  while (l != NULL) {
    l->next = wipe(l->data, l->next);
    l = l->next;
  }
}

/* helper function to construct a list */
List * mk(int v, List * n) {
  List * l = malloc(sizeof(*l));
  
  l->data = v;
  l->next = n;
  return l;
}

/* print the list */
void pr(List * l)
{
  while (l != NULL) {
    printf("%d ", l->data);
    l = l->next;
  }
  putchar('\n');
}


int main()
{
  List * l = mk(1, mk(2, mk(1, mk(3, mk(3, mk(2, mk(1, mk(4, NULL))))))));
  
  pr(l);
  simplify(l);
  pr(l);
  
  /* free the rest of the list */
  while (l) {
    List * n = l->next;
    
    free(l);
    l = n;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1 2 1 3 3 2 1 4 
1 2 3 4 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==3988== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3988== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3988== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3988== Command: ./a.out
==3988== 
1 2 1 3 3 2 1 4 
1 2 3 4 
==3988== 
==3988== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3988==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3988==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 1,088 bytes allocated
==3988== 
==3988== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3988== 
==3988== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==3988== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

That way have the complexity O(n<sup>2</sup>)

A faster way is to first sort the elements in the list then remove the duplicates, allowing to have the complexity of the sort so possibly O(n*log(n)) (probably using a temporary array to sort)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you need a recursive function that appends a number to a list only in case when the number is not present already in the list.

If so then the recursive function can look for example like

```
int append( list **head, int val )
{
    if ( *head == NULL )
    {
        *head = malloc( sizeof( **head ) );
        int success = *head != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            ( *head )->data = val;
            ( *head )->next = NULL;
        }

        return success;
    }
    else if ( ( *head )->data != val )
    {
        return append( &( *head )->next, val );
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And if in main you have a declaration like this

```
list *head = NULL;
```

then the function can be called for example like

```
append( &head, val );
```

Or like

```
if ( append( &head, val ) )
{
    printf( "The value %d is appended to the list.\n", val );
}
```